# sort images based on their color

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have some images from stones. Stone colors are creamy and I want to classify images based on their difference in color.I want to give the lightest stone grade 0 and to the darkest stone grade 10 and classify others between these two. Stones are very similar but their color difference is detectable by eyes.
I know if stones where all blue for example I could classify them based on R part of RGB color. But what about creamy color?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload some sample images ? Have you successfully segmented the stones from the background? If not then devising an algorithm for sorting on the basis of color won't work well due to background noise.

Comment: @ZdaR I uploaded images from stones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to go to the complexity of installing a compiler and **OpenCV** and writing/compiling Python/C++ code to get the mean lightness of your images. You can just use **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows too.

Basically, you could look at the *"Lightness"* in **HSL** colourspace or in the **Lab** colourspace.

---

Let's look at **HSL** first.

```
# Resize stone down to one average pixel, convert to HSL colourspace and print
convert stone1.jpg -resize 1x1 -colorspace HSL txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,65535,hsl
0,0: (4228.92,19250.9,52587.2)  #104BCD  hsl(23.2305,29.375%,80.2429%)
```

So the lightness of `stone1.jpg` in HSL is 80.24%. Let's try `stone2.jpg`:

```
convert stone2.jpg -resize 1x1 -colorspace HSL txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,65535,hsl
0,0: (7387.85,27252.5,57243)  #1D6ADF  hsl(40.5833,41.5846%,87.3472%)
```

So, `stone2.jpg` is lighter at 87.35%

Let's simplify the output to show only the Lightness:

```
convert stone1.jpg -colorspace HSL -format "%[fx:int(100*mean.b)]" info:
80
```

and `stone2.jpg`:

```
convert stone2.jpg -colorspace HSL -format "%[fx:int(100*mean.b)]" info:
87
```

---

Let's look at **Lab** colourspace now.

```
convert stone1.jpg -resize 1x1 -colorspace Lab txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,65535,cielab
0,0: (53895.2,1140.43,2057.36)  #D20408  cielab(82.2388%,1.74018%,3.13933%)
```

So, `stone1.jpg` has a **Lab** Lightness of 82.24%, let's look at `stone2.jpg`:

```
convert stone2.jpg -resize 1x1 -colorspace Lab txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,65535,cielab
0,0: (59395,-21.0391,2545.27)  #E7000A  cielab(90.6309%,-0.0321036%,3.88383%)
```

So, `stone2.jpg` has a lightness of 90.6%.

What if we want the simpler form?

```
convert stone1.jpg -colorspace Lab -format "%[fx:int(100*mean.r)]" info:
82
```

---

What are the percentages of? They are the percentage white, so pure white would be 100% and pure black would be 0%. Quick test...

```
convert xc:black -colorspace Lab txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,65535,cielab
0,0: (0,-0.5,-0.5)  #000000000000  cielab(0%,-0.000762951%,-0.000762951%)

convert xc:white -colorspace Lab txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,65535,cielab
0,0: (65535,0.125,-1.69336)  #FFFF00000000  cielab(100%,0.000190738%,-0.0025839%)
```

---

What if you have a whole directory full of stone samples and you want the **HSL** Lightness values for each?

```
convert stone* -colorspace HSL -format "%f:%[fx:int(100*mean.b)]\n" info:
stone1.jpg:80
stone2.jpg:87
stone3.jpg:75
stone4.jpg:92
```

Comment: Do you know where is documentation for the syntax used in the `-format` options.  LIke this one: `%[fx:int(100*mean.b)`. I have also seen stuff like this in the wild: `%[fx:floor(quantumrange*r)]`. This does not seemed to be covered [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php)

Comment: @BryanK I think you mean this https://imagemagick.org/script/fx.php

Answer (score 2):

> I want to classify images based on their difference in color.I want to give the lightest stone grade 0 and to the darkest stone grade 10 and classify others between these two. Stones are very similar but their color difference is detectable by eyes.

If you want to order them from light to dark, and take into account the hue, the RGB colour space is not well suited. You should have a look at the [Lab colour space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) or maybe the [Hue Saturation Lightness (HSL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) colour space.

By converting the images into one of these colour spaces, and then taking the average, you can then sort into lightness, and one or two axes of colour/hue. (This is assuming the image content is mostly homogenous.)